# What happens when an invalid stream header exception occurs?

Tags: java

When using socket programming, there is an invalid stream header exception, and I don't know where the problem occurs after searching for a long time.

I confirmed that the object sent on the sender side is inherited serialized and sent using `writeObject()`.The object received on the receiving end is inherited serializable and sent using `readObject()`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There's really not enough to go on in the question at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

When an `ObjectOutputStream` is created, it writes a so-called stream header to the output stream it's wrapping. When an `ObjectInputStream` is created, it tries to read that stream header from the input stream it's wrapping. If it reads something else than the stream header, then it is invalid (e.g. because it is reading something that was not created with `ObjectOutputStream`)

Generally, it means one of the following things:

1. You created an `ObjectInputStream` to read data which was not written by an `ObjectOutputStream`, but by something else
2. You created **one** `ObjectOutputStream` to write objects, but created multiple `ObjectInputStream`s to read that data; the second and subsequent instances will produce an *"invalid stream header"* error, because the stream header was only sent when `ObjectOutputStream` was created, and was consumed by the first instance.
3. You're using some composite protocol, and have read or buffered too much data before switching to an `ObjectInputStream`, and thus the stream header was already consumed from the underlying input stream.

Comment: The second item above is where my problem lies. thank you.